# Matrices with unknown elements

Tags: matrices

Now trying to solve matrices.

If

$$A = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-1&b\\
c&-1\\\end{array}\right]$$

What are the elements *b* and *c* so that $$A^{2}=2A^{T}$$

How to solve this kind of exercise? What are the step by step instructions for this kind of exercise?

Comment: Compute $A^2$ and $2A^T$ and compare the elements of both matrices. They should be equal to one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you solve for both A<sup>2</sup> and 2A<sup>T</sup>, you can set each index equal to each other and solve for b and c that way.

-2 = bc + 1 
2c = -2b

And so on with all the indexes. Since each term will contain b and c, use substitution to solve for one then the other.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$1)$ $A^2=A\cdot A$

$2)$ $A^T = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-1&c\\
b&-1\\\end{array}\right]$

$3)$ $2A^T = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-2&2c\\
2b&-2\\\end{array}\right]$

Comment: I got

$$A^{2}  = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
bc+1&-2b\\
 -2c&bc+1\\\end{array}\right]$$

and

$$2A^{T}  = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
 -2&2c\\
 2b& -2\\\end{array}\right]$$

But what now, how to continue? How should I interpret this?

Comment: @MiMaKo: Now each term must to be equal. For example, $bc+1=-2$, $-2b=2c$, ...

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how to solve b and c from this equation? (Sorry, It's been many years I studied maths, so I don't remember anymore). I get:

$$bc + 1 = -2$$ 

$$bc = -3$$ 

So now I know that bc is -3, but how to get the solution for only b and only for c?

Comment: @MiMaKo: You also know that $-2b=2c\to b=-c$ and then, using your last expression, $c^2=3\to c=\pm \sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a lot. I actually got that same solution but felt so unconfident with this exercise. So thank you for the support!

Comment: @MiMaKo: you are very welcome!